# device rotated but screen not stretches 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, device-orientation, landscape-portrait

in my iphone app i have returned yes in the following method  ,its worked  and screens are rotating but contents are not fitting to the screen when its in the landscape mode

following is the code which i used

```
  - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
         return YES;

    }
```

following is my output [image]

how can i fit the contents of the screen to the screen size when its rotated,,can any one help me, thanx in advance,,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `reset the views frame` when the device is about to be rotated. This should be usually done in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method.

You can also simply use `autoResizingMask` which will automatically resize the view when its superView frame changes.

```
// Add this line in loadView method
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | 
                             UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: thanx for ur reply,,i have worked this but its not working - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    }
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    //return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    return YES;
}

Comment: You should add this line `loadView` method.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the interface builder?

Answer (score 0):

read this tutorial:

http://www.shinstudio.com/blog/programming/rotating-view-in-iphone-app/

implementing `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` will be solution