# search bar and table views are not fitting to the screen in land scape mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, landscape, uiinterfaceorientation

i am creating the search bar and table view programatically using the following code

```
UISearchBar* searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,40)];
searchBar.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:searchBar];

UITableView* tblView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 41, 320, 400)];
tblView.delegate = self;
tblView.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:tblView];
```

now i made the return value yes in the following method to to rotate the screen wrt device orientation

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

    return YES;
}
```

and i used following code in `loadView`

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

following is my output

[image]
but still search bar and table views are not fitting to the screen in landscape mode, what should i do can any one help me,,thanx in advance

Comment: Exact Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7256785/491980

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have told the view to resize but you haven't told the search bar you created to resize try something like:

```
searchbar.autorezingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

do the same for the table view.

see if that gives you the result you are looking for. IF that doesn't work you can always resize the frame of the search bar and table view after rotation.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling this autoresizingMask in ViewWillAppear method.

Answer (score -1):

if you assign frame of any object...you have to provide new frame when it rotates.
Give a new frame in following method based on toInterfaceOrientation.

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```